# Existence of ''positive'' solution to a linear system implies existence of positive/negative basis element?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm encountering this statement and still haven't found out if it is true or not.

Assume $\left\{e_1,...,e_k\right\}$ is a basis of $\ker A$, where $A$ is a matrix of order $n$. Suppose there exists $x \in int(\mathbb{R}_{+}^n)$ such that $Ax=0$.

My question is whether we can conclude that there exists a basis element $e_i$ ($1\le i \le k$) such that $e_i \in int(\mathbb{R}_{+}^n) \cup int(\mathbb{R}_{-}^n)$ ?

Notation elaboration: $int(\mathbb{R}_{+}^n)/int(\mathbb{R}_{-}^n)$ denotes all points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all positive/negative components, respectively.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $e_1=(-1,2)$ and $e_2=(2,-1)$ form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Now take $A=0$ so that $ker A=\mathbb R^2$.